# TextField actions are not triggered on Android

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-android

There is a problem in Android Web Chrome. When Text inputType text or name does not work onsubmit and it is not possible to send a request. But for some reason, if you set the TextInputType.emailAddress parameter, then the submit key on the keyboard becomes a "right arrow" and everything works as it should work. What could be the reason for this behavior?

```
TextFormField(
        enabled: isEnabled ?? true,
        obscureText: isObscured ?? false,
        controller: controller,

        keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
        textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
        minLines: widget.minLines ?? 1,
        maxLines: widget.maxLines ?? 1,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          fillColor: AppColors.fieldBackground,
          filled: true,
          hintText: widget.hintText,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: (Dimens.buttonHeight - 14) / 2,
            bottom: (Dimens.buttonHeight - 14) / 2,
            left: Dimens.horizontalPadding,
            right: Dimens.horizontalPadding,
          ),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            textLength = value.length;
          });
        },
        focusNode: focusNode,
        onFieldSubmitted: (query) {
        if (query.length > 2 || query.isEmpty) {
          serviceLocator<SearchBloc>().add(
            FiltersChanged(query: query),
          );
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        } else {
          Messages.showInfoMessage(
              context,
              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.searchFieldShortQueryTitle,
              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.searchFieldShortQueryMessage);
        }
      },
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the input action manually and it should work as expected

```dart
TextField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
)
```

Comment: Thansk for asking, but i tried to use go and done TextInputAction, but it doesnt work for me